# Can a GAS Library be used a script template?

Tags: google-apps-script

I've built a system within a spreadsheet that uses custom menus to move through a process. The script is stored in a template file, which is generated from a separate overview spreadsheet (via script) when required. Basically, each newly generated spreadsheet is a Product Tracker.

When the template is copied for a new Product Tracker the script is out-of-date if the template is updated. Would extracting the bound script from the template and creating a library from it make sense for my application?

I've nearly finished developing the template for a particular product, but I would like to roll it out for multiple products with slightly different templates which means it would be difficult to have a generic script that could be published within my Google Workspace Domain as an add-on (would probably need an add-on for each product).

Reading up on Libraries, Google warns that they can be slow. Currently, each script takes around 10 seconds to run and performs operations such as hide/show sheets, change tab colours, add/remove protection, send emails etc. There are already calls to another library, would this affect it as well? Would this be really slow as a library?

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
There are 10 buttons on the menu, one for each stage. The API's below are used at every stage. Reading through the execution logs, the scripts vary in execution time from 4 - 6 seconds depending on the stage.

```
"oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui"
  ],
```

Edit2:
Bastardised the code to remove certain information.

The script below is similar across around 9 scripts.

```
function doThing() {

 
  var activeUser = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var activeUserName = activeUser.split('@domain.com')[0]

  // spreadsheets
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  // sheets
  const 1 = ss.getSheetByName("1.");
  const 1b= ss.getSheetByName("1b.");
  const 2 = ss.getSheetByName("2.");
  const 3 = ss.getSheetByName("3.");
  const 4 = ss.getSheetByName("4.");
  const 5 = ss.getSheetByName("5.");
  const 6 = ss.getSheetByName("6.");
  const 7 = ss.getSheetByName("7.");
  const 8 = ss.getSheetByName("8");
  const 9 = ss.getSheetByName("9.");
  const shipSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Shipping");
  const buildEvalSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Build Evaluation");

  // build Number
  const buildNumber = 1.getRange(buildNumberCell).getValue();

  // get the active user email address and log it 
  Logger.log("Active User Email: " + activeUser);
  Logger.log("Running 3");

  // this prevents non-authorised users from running the script
  // see the permissionGroups object in the Variables script file for more information

  // set a variable relative to the department using the buttons
  var criteria = 'department'
  // run the permissions function in the library
  var automationPermission = EmailPermissionsLibrary.checkPermissions(activeUserName, criteria);
  // run if true
  if (automationPermission) {

    // set tab colours for previous & current 
    1.setTabColor("GREEN");
    1b.setTabColor("GREEN");
    2.setTabColor("GREEN");
    3.setTabColor("GREEN");

    // protect
    3.activate()
    protect();

    statusUpdate()

    if (emailBoolean) {
      // send information to Sales and Shipping

      //create html email
      var htmlEmail = "<html><body>";
      htmlEmail += "<p>Hello,</p>"
      htmlEmail += "<p>" + buildNumber + " message</p>"

      // send email

      MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: 'email@domain.com',
        subject: buildNumber + " message",
        htmlBody: htmlEmail,
        replyTo: activeUser
      });
    }
    shipping()
    buildEvalShow()
  }
  // error message if the user is not authorised
  else {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('This account does not have authorisation')
    Logger.log(activeUser + " does not have required permissions")
  }
}
```

Will this script be slow as a library?

```
// set a variable relative to the department using the buttons
  var criteria = 'department'

  // run the permissions function in the library
  var automationPermission = EmailPermissionsLibrary.checkPermissions(activeUserName, criteria);

  // log permission
  Logger.log(automationPermission)

  // run if true
  if (automationPermission) {

    Logger.log("Running");

    // show sheet
    sheet.activate();

    // check that the #### hasn't already ran by doing a row count

    // if it hasn't, the following should return 1 which will be the titles
    var sheetR = sheet.getLastRow();

    if (sheetR <= 1) {     

      // summary table size
      const sumTableRowCount = 12; 
      const sumTableColCount = 3;

      for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {

        var results = eval("prodQC" + [i] + "Sheet");

        sumTable = sheet2.getRange(45, 2, sumTableRowCount, sumTableColCount).getValues();

        var something = sheet2.getLastRow() + 2;

        // create the title
        var title = "Title " + i;

        // write the title
        sheet.getRange(sheetR, 1).setValue(title);

        // Remove checks
        if (i >= 2) {
          var sheetRL= sheet.getLastRow();
          sheet.getRange(buildEvalSheetLastRow, 4).removeCheckboxes();
          sheet.getRange(buildEvalSheetLastRow, 6).removeCheckboxes();
        }

        // recount last row and add 1 to stop overwrite
        var sheetR = sheet.getLastRow() + 1;

        // write the QC summary table to the sheet
        sheet.getRange(sheetR, 1, sumTableRowCount, sumTableColCount).setValues(sumTable);

        // set checkboxes next to values on JIRA col
        sheet.getRange(sheetR, 4, sumTableRowCount, 1).insertCheckboxes();

        // set checkboxes next to values on the CPACC col
        sheet.getRange(sheetR, 6, sumTableRowCount, 1).insertCheckboxes();

        // add data validation to the Choose One col

        // last row
        var sheetR = sheet.getLastRow();

        // set range to be from row 3,  col 8, to last row
        var range = sheet.getRange(4, 8, sheetR, 1);

        // set the data validation to only accept values from the array
        range .setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
          .setAllowInvalid(false)
          .requireValueInList(
            [
              "list item 1",
              "list item 2",
              "listed item 3"
            ],
            true)
          .build()
        );

        // add data validation to the Impact and Deadline cols

        // set range to be from row 3, col 11, to last row for 2 cols
        var cols = sheet.getRange(4, 11, sheetR, 2);

        // set the data validation to only accept values from the array
        cols .setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
          .setAllowInvalid(false)
          .requireValueInList(
            [
              "1",
              "2",
              "3",
              "4",
              "5"
            ],
            true)
          .build()
        );
      }

      // remove all non-failures 

      // last row
      var sheetR = sheet.getLastRow();

      // range of values from A1, across 3 columns and to the last row
      var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheetR, 3);

      // Default text from Production QC Template  
      var removeVal1 = "something";

      // Modified text when the QC is complete
      var removeVal2 = "something else";

      // Default text from Production QC Template  
      var removeVal3 = "another thing";

      // get values from the range to check in the For loop below
      var rangeVals = range.getValues();

      // Reverse the 'for' loop.
      for (let i = rangeVals.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

        // if matching values above are in the target range, delete the row
        if (
          rangeVals[i][2] === removeVal1 ||
          rangeVals[i][2] === removeVal2 ||
          rangeVals[i][2] === removeVal3) {

          buildEvalSheet.deleteRow(i + 1)
        }
      }
    } else { // if there is already more rows than expected).alert('this has done something');

    }

  } else {  // error message if the user is not authorised
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('This account does not have authorisation')
    Logger.log(activeUser + " does not have required permissions")

  }
}
```

Comment: Hello there! Please share the script that you talk about, so we all can take a look and check its optimization. To give you an answer adjusted to your scenario, please link the docs cited in the question.

Comment: @Jacques-GuzelHeron, I have added a sample of the code. There are 9 other scripts which are very similar.

Comment: After studying this question I don't have a clear picture of the goal. As far as I can see your code works, is that correct on your end? If so, what is the question here?

Comment: Hi. My question is: would running this script as a library be incredibly slow? I have this as a bound script in a template, but every time it runs the new file created from the template will have a fixed version of the code bound to it. If I update the template file, the previously generated script is not updated as well. If I run as a library I can store the script there, as the 'single source of truth', but would calling it from a library have a significant impact on performance? Thanks

Comment: I don't see any reasons about why it should go slow. It works *normally* on my side, do you have any performance decline on yours? If so please share the minimal amount of code that replicates the performance loss.

Comment: Great, thanks for trying! I was asking more for general information, as I read on Google Documentation for GAS that running as a library may be slow. This opens up a lot of possibilities for me now!! Thanks for your help